# Compare two columns to get data that doesn't same

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanna compare 2 tables to get data that doesn't same.

```
tb1              tb2
==============   ==============
|id| doc_name|   |id| doc_summ|
==============   ==============
|1 | 01180543|   |1 | 01180543|
|2 | Chord   |   ============== 
==============
```

I wanna compare `doc_name` and `doc_summ`. from that example the result must be `Chord`.

```
$q = mysql_query(" SELECT t1.doc_name FROM tb1 as t1, tb2 as t2 WHERE t1.doc_name != t2.doc_summ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    $doc_copy = $row['doc_name'];
}
```

but the result still returns all of data. what's wrong? thank you :)

Comment: what data should you compare? can you give sample records and desired result?

Comment: Suppose `tb2` also contained the row `|2|Guitar|`? Would you also want that output?

Comment: @JimGarrison no, I just wanna get the data from `tb1` only :)

Comment: In that case, @JohnWoo's answer below is correct.

Comment: @bruine removed syntax error from my answer.

Comment: @Ankur there is no syntax error from your answer, i think.. cmiiw

Comment: @JimGarrison what is the different with Ankur answer ? I've tried Ankur answer, and it's done well also..

Comment: It's a slightly more modern idiom (and he provided a demo).  You might try "explain plan" on both and see if there's a difference in how the DB engine optimizes them.

Comment: @bruine [here's the result from both queries](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1394c/3)

Comment: @JimGarrison thanks, it's the first time I know about 'explain plan'. I learn many things today

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can join both tables using `LEFT JOIN`. What it does is it only display the records of table 1 if it has no match on table 2.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tb1 a
        LEFT JOIN tb2 b
            ON a.doc_name = b.doc_summ
WHERE   b.doc_summ IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1394c/1)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.doc_name 
FROM   t1 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT t2.doc_summ 
                  FROM   t2 
                  WHERE  t2.doc_summ = t1.doc_name)
```

The mistake in your query is that you are joining two table, so you will always find a row in t2 which would not satisfy the where condition therefore displaying all data.

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fdf7c/1/0)**

Comment: can someone please format the code, i don't knw how to do the same using mobile version.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this

```
select tb1.doc_name from tb1 left join tb2 on tb1.id = tb2.id where tb1.doc_name != tb2.doc_summ;
```